# PostgreSQL: json_agg in join results in nested array

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

For my problem, I'm using `json_agg` in join to aggregate my result. 
But this results in a nested array sequence.

Query:

```
 SELECT c.*,
       json_agg(ci.national_id) AS national_id,
       json_agg(a.address) AS address
FROM company AS c
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT company_id,
          json_agg(json_build_object('value', national_id, 'country', country_code)) AS national_id
   FROM company_identification
   GROUP BY company_id) AS ci ON ci.company_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT company_id,
          json_agg(address.*) AS address
   FROM address
   GROUP BY company_id) AS a ON a.company_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Result:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "c876967d-dd8b-4068-88f4-57a438a2015c",
    "name": "S.A.1",
    "nationalId": [
      [
        {
          "value": "string",
          "country": "CL"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "address": [
      [
        {
          "id": "d1362084-e652-4900-ba51-86352b7a8ce5",
          "streetName": "First Avenue"
        },
        {
          "id": "0f785a23-6eb3-44ea-9254-34a6f47ff638",
          "streetName": "Second Avenue"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "38557302-a6a3-4484-ae1b-27edc8c4e906",
    "name": "S.A.",
    "nationalId": [
      [
        {
          "value": "Chile",
          "country": "CL"
        },
        {
          "value": "Colombia",
          "country": "CO"
        },
        {
          "value": "Mexico",
          "country": "MX"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "address": [
      [
        {
          "id": "d1362084-e652-4900-ba51-86352b7a8ce5",
          "streetName": "First Avenue"
        },
        {
          "id": "0f785a23-6eb3-44ea-9254-34a6f47ff638",
          "streetName": "Second Avenue"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see the `nationalId` and `address` fileds contains nested arrays.

sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9fde6/2

Output from sqlfiddle:

```
| id |  name |                                   national_id |
|----|-------|-----------------------------------------------|
|  1 | S.A.1 | [[{"value" : "Chile", "country" : "CL "}]]    |
|  2 |  S.A. | [[{"value" : "Colombia", "country" : "CO "}]] |
```

The national_id field should not contain array within array

```
[[ ... ]]
```

Desired Output:

```
| id |  name |                                   national_id |
|----|-------|-----------------------------------------------|
|  1 | S.A.1 | [{"value" : "Chile", "country" : "CL "}]      |
|  2 |  S.A. | [{"value" : "Colombia", "country" : "CO "}]   |
```

Comment: You don't clearly say what your query should return. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: The `JSON_AGG` function you're using will always return values as an array.  Can you update your question with some sample rows of how you want to see your data returned?  Also, if you can post a SQL Fiddle with the `DDL` and sample data to play with that would make it easier for us to help you out.  Here's one I started that you can modify - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/22202

Comment: Hi @ravioli, thanks for your inputs. I have updated your http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/22202 url and added the desired output required.

Comment: since i'm using `JSON_AGG` twice it results in `[[ .... ]]`. I want the output as `[...]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for posting the example to SQL Fiddle.  I think the reason for your double array is that you're using `JSON_AGG` around `national_id` in the outer `SELECT`.  Try removing it and the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
  "c".*,
--  JSON_AGG(ci.national_id) AS national_id
  ci.national_id
FROM "company" AS "c"
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT "company_id",
    JSON_AGG(
      JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'value', national_id, 
        'country', country_code
      )
    ) AS national_id
  FROM "company_identification"
  GROUP BY "company_id"
) AS "ci" ON "ci"."company_id" = "c"."id"
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT "company_id",
    JSON_AGG(address.*) AS address
  FROM "address"
  GROUP BY "company_id"
) AS "a" ON "a"."company_id" = "c"."id"
-- GROUP BY "c"."id", "c"."name"
;
```

You already did the `JSON_AGG` in the two `LEFT JOINs` for `national_id` and `address` and they are both grouped by `company_id`, so there should be no need for an additional `JSON_AGG` in your outer `SELECT`.

Let me know if that works.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9fde6/8

Comment: No prob bob. :)